# Ideal approch for reading data from MANY Excel files(xls format)

Tags: c#, excel

Hello Everyone and thanks for your attention.

(I have already googled my question and please understand that my question is different from those that asked for best way to read a LARGE excel file not many or for writing into Excel files, I just want to read them)

At the moment i am working on an small program that it's purpose can be defined as to reading and analyzing anywhere between a handful to a couple of hundred and possibly thousands of log files in excel format to collect statistical results, now i know the decision to save logs as Excel is odd, but i am not the one who decided that, thats just how it is for me.

as you might guess what i plan to do is to read data from every and each excel file and load it into memory as a C# model class before processing.
The way i am reading the file excel files is based on my experience from using Interop, Opening an Excel file, reading data from few cells i need then close that file and move unto next and let another thread handle processing.

I have already tried testing my approach using Interop and it was super slow.  Here is the part code that handeled the reading

```
                List<string> strings = new List<string>();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = null;

            try
            {
                string str;
                int rCnt;
                int cCnt;
                int row = 0;
                int column = 0;

                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
                row = range.Rows.Count;
                column = range.Columns.Count;
                strings.Clear();

                for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= row; rCnt++)
                {
                    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= column; cCnt++)
                    {
                        str = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2?.ToString();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                            strings.Add(str);
                    }
                }

                xlWorkBook.Close(true);
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
    catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exception.Log();
            }
            finally
            {
                //https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/
                if (xlWorkBook != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
                if (xlWorkSheet != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                if (range != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(range);
                if (xlApp != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
            return strings.ToArray();
```

So in order to resolve my problm i am hoping to find someone who faced similar problem in past and found a way around it or answer some questions i have:

- What is the fastest free library when it comes to reading from multiple Excel files(as in it doesn't take too long opening and closing files or bother reading to the end of file or reading it from start each time when it goes to get a cell)
- Would it improve the speed if i just loaded the entire excel file into memory and read it there and is there a Library that works like that?
- Would it Improve speed if I loaded files that are in 2 different drives from 2 different thread?

Comment: Can you access the Excel file using the MS ACE driver instead? It looks like you're just reading data, not performing any actual *Interop*. BTW, you're not marshaling any of the COM objects you created, so you'll have hundreds of Excel processes in memory.

Comment: @Jimi oops sorry i actually wrote marshaling in the code but it was in finally so i didn't notice i didn't copied them, i forgot that piece of code, i will upload rest of the original code now

Comment: All right, not important then, just a note would do. But, have you tried to read the data as a *Table*, using the driver instead of Interop (which also requires an Excel installation). BTW2, that marshaling doesn't actually mashal the COM objects. You need something more complex than that. The code you have now forces you to call `GC.Collect()`. Possibly more than once.

Comment: There is [another stackexchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this. It is offtopic on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jimi Sorry for late reply, I was implementing your answer for use of MS ACE driver with unit testing based on [This](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9014/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-c-without-interop), The results were very good, speed of getting a specific cell in a 300kb xls file was improved by a whole 2.2 seconds and reduced to less than 40ms, with 10 excel files the time for getting each in each file remains under 80ms and overall speed was reduced about 18 seconds. If you post it as an answer i can select if no one comes up with a better solution.

Comment: You don't have that many choices, unless you want to use some pre-built library, but I don't think this will improve the overall performance. Anyway, I just suggested a different tool. If the code you wrote meets your expectations, post an answer yourself. Maybe I can give you some suggestions, looking at the code. The important thing is you get rid of the Interop baggage.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use nuget packages? If so, have a look at the ExcelDataReader library and its ExcelReaderFactory. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader

For xls files, I would use `var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)`, then you can use the reader to read it into a dataset `var data = reader.AsDataSet();`

You can also tell it if the first row contains column names before you read the dataset, such as `reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;`

If you've got .xlsx files, you can use  `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);`